# What interprets Perl filename checks?

Tags: perl, filenames, sanitization

The code 'if(-e "filename")' tests for existence of a file with name filename in the directory the script containing that code is executed in.

What is doing the name check? Perl? The OS? Bash on POSIX-os?

Would 'if(-e "cat string")' execute the cat command on Linux?

I want to know in order to be able to avert undesired file access like "../file" would access a file in the parent directory.

To share my check code:

```
if($folder =~ m/$([\\]?\.[\\]?\.|[\\]?\\|[\\]?\/|[\\]?\?|[\\]?*|[\\]?:|[\\]?\||[\\]?\"|[\\]?\<|[\\]?\>)^|$([\\]?\.[\\]?\.|[\\]?\\|[\\]?\/|[\\]?\?|[\\]?*|[\\]?:|[\\]?\||[\\]?\"|[\\]?\<|[\\]?\>)\/|\/([\\]?\.[\\]?\.|[\\]?\\|[\\]?\/|[\\]?\?|[\\]?*|[\\]?:|[\\]?\||[\\]?\"|[\\]?\<|[\\]?\>)\/|\/([\\]?\.[\\]?\.|[\\]?\\|[\\]?\/|[\\]?\?|[\\]?*|[\\]?:|[\\]?\||[\\]?\"|[\\]?\<|[\\]?\>)^|\$'[^']*'/)
{
    #error
}
```

Updated regular expression:

```
if($folder =~ m/(\/|\\)|$([\\]?\.[\\]?\.^|$[\\]?(\*|\?)^|\$'[^']*'/)
{
    #error
}
```

Explanation: $folder shall be a pure filename already. If it contains Windows or POSIX path separators or is (any escaped) parent directory back link or is (any escaped) wild card (as that matches the first matching file and returns true on Mac OS X at least) or contains a C ANSI escape sequence anywhere, signal error. Anything else, even if not legal or if shady, should simply return a "file not exists" and thus may be supplied to an 'if(-e $folder)'.

Comment: Have you looked at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html?

Comment: I hadn't. Thanks. Now I have. :-)

Comment: Just looking at the first member of the main alternation (`...|...|...|...`), I can tell that you have the line positions backwards. A `$` matches the *end* of the line; a `^` the beginning. You'll match nothing by putting dollar signs at the beginning--*unless* you're doing a multi-line match.

Comment: you're right. Sorry everyone interested. It has to be ^...$. I'll leave it to users to correct it.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3ABasename) if you want to strip paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operating system does. Perl's call to `-e` (as well as others like `-s`) are implemented by calling the C library function `stat`.

There is no shell involed, and therefore `"cat some_file"` will not be executed. Instead the OS looks for a file called "cat some_file".

`stat` can, of course, be called with relative path names. If you don't want that then strip away everything but the file name + extension. There are [Perl modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) for this kind of thing.

I don't want to debug/look into your proposed regular expression because it is, quite honestly, completey unreadable and unmaintainable.

Comment: thanks, starting from the filename only is a good start, see my comment to cdarke s answer. That will make the re more easy. You know a way to make re s readable and maintainable? Getting to know such a way is welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

1. *Who does the name check?*  In the end, all file I/O is done by the operating system, unless you are a device driver. Perl makes the request to the operating system to do that check, although it might go through the C runtime-library to do so. Why are you asking?
2. *Would 'if(-e "cat string")' execute the cat command on Linux?* No. Wrong syntax. Open the file then read it yourself. OK, if you *must* use cat, use `system`, or `xq`, depending on what you want to do with the output.
3. *Do you want to know in order to be able to avert undesired file access like "../file"*? Why is that undesired? Is it the `..`, or the leading directory name?

   ```
   use File::Basename;
   my $name = basename($filename);
   ```

will remove leading directory names.

Comment: removing leading directory names will be a better start than my original approach. The filename argument shall be a file name only thus anything else is undesired, see my comment to dan1111 s answer

Answer (score 0):

Perl does not use the shell to check the file for existence.  You can treat `-e` as an internal Perl function, despite its strange appearance.  It can't be used as a sneaky way to execute a shell command.

I don't think you need such a complicated regex.  If you don't want the user to be able to enter a parent directory, just ensure that the filename starts with a word character (on Linux, anyway):

```
if($folder =~ m/^\W/)
{
    print "path doesn't start with an alphanumeric character!";
}
```

Of course, enforcing a path in this way is a poor security method if that is your concern.  Instead, you should set your permissions properly.

Comment: You're right, file/folder permissions can and should be used to avoid access to folders which must not be read from. If a folder may be read from, checking the file access argument for being purely a filename (ie. strip directory parts) and a nice one as such (which still requires some checks *) suffices, as I'm going to agree to an earlier answer above in some minutes. *: \.\. on linux would be the name of the parent directory which would exist and might be usually accessible)